# React-Bootstrap tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap to create 2 tabs which will display some data i pull from an api, but they seem to be displaying as buttons.

my tabs:
[image: what they show as]
documentation:
[image: what the documentation shows it should look like]

I am importing them correctly (i think) other react bootstrap components from here are working fine

```
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormLabel,
  FormControl,
  FormText,
  Button,
  Tooltip,
  OverlayTrigger,
  Tabs,
  Tab,
} from "react-bootstrap";
```

and this is how i use them

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey={2}
                id="uncontrolled-tab-example"
                className="nav-item"
          >
            <Tab eventKey={1} title="Full">
              <br />
              <MaverickFullResult items={this.state.results} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={2} title="Summary">
              <br />
              <MaverickSummaryResult items={this.state.results} />
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
```

Comment: it seams like bootstrap is not loaded at all. Can you try refreshing your page.

Comment: no sadly it doesn't seem to be that

Comment: do you have this in index.html? <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

Comment: no index.html, though i think it is imported and loaded correctly as other bootstrap components are working fine

Answer (score 2):

You need to import below css file in index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: This is the right way to import file in react.js  eater in index or app.js

Comment: there is a custom css style which applies to some of the outputs to the data i have so it seems that that is affecting Tabs, i think i will need to apply custom styling to get these to look correct